# Web service not returning data when called from code

Tags: wcf, soapui

Got stuck on an issue.
I'm consuming an external web service and I'm trying to receive data from a web method.
This web method returns an array of a particular object.
When I call the method from my code (C#, Service Reference) the response is an empty array, but when i call it from SOAP UI with exactly the same parameters I get the array with data.

What could be the problem? any Idea?

Tks

Answer (score 0):

Ceck the header information, the content type, the parameters. Make sure everything is exactly the same.

Soap UI is obviously setting more things in the background you just need to make sure you replicate it exactly.

Use something like Fiddler and inspect each call, this way you will notice the differences very quickly and you should be able to craft your call correctly.